# etherpad-lite-cf doesn't work on ibm bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, etherpad

i have a problem with Bluemix. I would like to install a Etherpad-lite, but I get the following message when I try to create a pad:

UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0
TypeError: pad.collabClient is null in http://XXXXXXXX.mybluemix.net/javascripts/lib/ep_etherpad-lite/static/js/pad.js?callback=require.define at line 266'

UserAgent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setChannelState' of null in http://xxxxxxx.mybluemix.net/javascripts/lib/ep_etherpad-lite/static/js/pad.js?callback=require.define at line 266'

What can i do?

Comment: Can you share some of your code? I doubt anything specific with bluemix can cause the JavaScript error you are seeing

Comment: i used Etherpad v1.5.6 for cloudfoundry(etherpad-lite-cf.zip) form here:
https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/etherpad-lite-cf/releases

i only edit the settings.json

Answer (score 0):

I have less reputations, so I can not comment on this. Have you setup backend database ?   I have my own Etherpad-lite up and running for months without any issue. I had to disable "ep_ldapauth": "0.2.0",though. I used mysql service as my backend, and bind to it.